# Adding NumberPicker to AlertDialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, android-dialog, numberpicker

**Short Version:**

I want to display a horizontal **NumberPicker** on the right hand side of each item of the "single-choice-items" **AlertDialog**.

**Long Version:**

I am using an **AlertDialog** of the "single-choice-items" type. It works fine. It displays a list of strings which I want.

Now, I want to use a **NumberPicker** (with numbers 1 to 5) with this "single-choice-items" **AlertDialog**. What I want is the **NumberPicker** to be displayed horizontally, on the right-hand-side of each of those strings of the **AlertDialog**.

I have no idea how to modify my "usual" **AlertDialog** to achieve this. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own layout for the AlertDialog then inflate the layout before you call show().

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_own_alert_with_picker,null));
dialog.show();
```